# React native : fetch keeps duplicating data on each refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, rest

I have a react native app in which I fetch data from an api like this

```
export const treatmentsList = (props) => {
const [treatments, setTreatments] = useState([]);
const healthcareUrl = // an url ..


async function getAllTreatmentsByPathwayId(id) {
  const url = healtcareUrl + '/api/v1/treatments/by-pathway/' + id;
  var token;
  await AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token').then((res) => {
    token = res;
  });
  return fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {  Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token },
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
}


  const getTreatmentOfPathway = async () => {
    await getAllTreatmentsByPathwayId(8).then((res) => {
      res.map((products) => {
        setTreatments((treatments) => [
          ...treatments,
          {
            id: products.id,
            isEffectuated: products.isEffectuated,
            name: products.treatmentType.name,
            description: products.treatmentType.description,
            image: products.treatmentType.image,
          },
        ]);
      });
    });
    return treatments;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getTreatmentOfPathway();
  }, []);

return (
<View>
{treatments.map(function (theItem, i) {return (
<View>
<Text>
{theItem.name}
<Text>
<View>)})}
</View>
);
}
```

the fetching works fine and I get my two treatments names rendered (in my case the two treatment names are laminectomy and prosthesis) but every time I make a change in Visual Studio Code and then press ctrl+s to save , the app refreshes duplicating these two names.
For example in the first render it shows
***laminectomy
prothesis***
after the second refresh it shows
***laminectomy
prothesis
laminectomy
prothesis***
after the third refresh it shows
***laminectomy
prothesis
laminectomy
prothesis
laminectomy
prothesis***
I mean why on each refresh it doesn't setTreatments([]) automatically like it is declared on the second line of the above code ?
The only solution that I found is to add `setTreatments([])` in  `getTreatmentOfPathway()`
like this

```
const getTreatmentOfPathway = async () => {
setTreatments([]); // setting the treatments empty 
    await getAllTreatmentsByPathwayId(8).then((res) => {
      res.map((products) => {
        setTreatments((treatments) => [
          ...treatments,
          {
            id: products.id,
            isEffectuated: products.isEffectuated,
            name: products.treatmentType.name,
            description: products.treatmentType.description,
            
            image: products.treatmentType.image,
          },
        ]);
      });
    });
    return treatments;
  };
```

Any one has an explanation and a solution PLEASE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. I understand your problem.

```
setTreatments((treatments) => [
      ...treatments,
      {
        id: products.id,
        isEffectuated: products.isEffectuated,
        name: products.treatmentType.name,
        description: products.treatmentType.description,
        
        image: products.treatmentType.image,
      },
    ]);
```

every time this code execute the array add just more element that are in the array. the `... operator` keep the array data and add more items.

you need to create a temp array and add the prodcuts in that after the iteration ends then set your state. like this.

```
    let temparray = []
    res.map((products) => {
          temparray.push({
                id: products.id,
                isEffectuated: products.isEffectuated,
                name: products.treatmentType.name,
                description: products.treatmentType.description,
                image: products.treatmentType.image,
              }}
          });

setTreatments(temparray)
```

Comment: thank you it works but any other solution without the use of any variable other than treatments